# Emulator keeps crashing when running

Tags: android

Hi i am trying to make an app which shows the location of a place and everytime i run my app on the android emulator and every-time time i run it keeps on crashing and it is displaying this message in the log cat down below. I am running android studio version 3.4.2. I would appreciate it if someone could help me with this problem.

The libary i loaded in was : implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:8.0.0'

```
2020-03-27 16:22:33.335 12756-12756/com.example.mappingexample E/SoLoader: couldn't find DSO to load: libmapbox-gl.so caused by: dlopen failed: "/data/data/com.example.mappingexample/lib-main/libmapbox-gl.so" has unexpected e_machine: 40 (EM_ARM)
2020-03-27 16:22:33.340 12756-12756/com.example.mappingexample E/Mbgl-LibraryLoader: Failed to load native shared library.
    com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader$WrongAbiError: APK was built for a different platform
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:645)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:577)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:525)
        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.module.loader.LibraryLoaderProviderImpl$SoLibraryLoader.load(LibraryLoaderProviderImpl.java:42)
        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.LibraryLoader.load(LibraryLoader.java:43)
        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.net.NativeConnectivityListener.<clinit>(NativeConnectivityListener.java:13)
        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.net.ConnectivityReceiver.instance(ConnectivityReceiver.java:43)
        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox.getInstance(Mapbox.java:67)
        at com.example.mappingexample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libmapbox-gl.so caused by: dlopen failed: "/data/data/com.example.mappingexample/lib-main/libmapbox-gl.so" has unexpected e_machine: 40 (EM_ARM)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.doLoadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:789)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:639)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:577) 
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:525) 
        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.module.loader.LibraryLoaderProviderImpl$SoLibraryLoader.load(LibraryLoaderProviderImpl.java:42) 
        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.LibraryLoader.load(LibraryLoader.java:43) 
        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.net.NativeConnectivityListener.<clinit>(NativeConnectivityListener.java:13) 
        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.net.ConnectivityReceiver.instance(ConnectivityReceiver.java:43) 
        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox.getInstance(Mapbox.java:67) 
        at com.example.mappingexample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
2020-03-27 16:22:33.344 12756-12756/com.example.mappingexample E/.mappingexampl: No implementation found for void com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.net.NativeConnectivityListener.initialize() (tried Java_com_mapbox_mapboxsdk_net_NativeConnectivityListener_initialize and Java_com_mapbox_mapboxsdk_net_NativeConnectivityListener_initialize__)
2020-03-27 16:22:33.344 12756-12756/com.example.mappingexample D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-03-27 16:22:33.345 12756-12756/com.example.mappingexample E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.mappingexample, PID: 12756
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.net.NativeConnectivityListener.initialize() (tried Java_com_mapbox_mapboxsdk_net_NativeConnectivityListener_initialize and Java_com_mapbox_mapboxsdk_net_NativeConnectivityListener_initialize__)
        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.net.NativeConnectivityListener.initialize(Native Method)
        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.net.NativeConnectivityListener.<init>(NativeConnectivityListener.java:27)
        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.net.ConnectivityReceiver.instance(ConnectivityReceiver.java:43)
        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox.getInstance(Mapbox.java:67)
        at com.example.mappingexample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
2020-03-27 16:22:33.360 12756-12756/com.example.mappingexample I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 12756 SIG: 9
```

Comment: I'm hitting a similar error, found this Github issue that may be tracking progress (no official solution yet): https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native-android/issues/416

Answer (score 4):

**You can resolve this issue by following these steps:**

*1. Go to Gradle (Module: App)*

*2. Add this code on `android {}`*

```
android {
packagingOptions {
    pickFirst '**/armeabi-v7a/libmapbox-gl.so'
    pickFirst '**/x86/libmapbox-gl.so'
    pickFirst '**/arm64-v8a/libmapbox-gl.so'
    pickFirst '**/x86_64/libmapbox-gl.so'
    pickFirst '**/x86/libmapbox-gl.so'
    }
}
```

[image]